# Prevent a layer to be moved out of the image

Tags: gimp

When moving layers, I'm often trying to fit layer to one of the sides of the image. The problem is, that there is nothing to stop the layer to be moved out of the image.

Imagine pushing a furniture to the wall with the eventuality that it will easily go through and fall on the pavement.

[image: the image of good and bad alignment]

Now I'm aware of the [alignment tool](http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-tool-align.html). With it, I can select the layer in question, in options select "Relative to... image" and then press one of the buttons.

But could I just lock whe image so that nothing can leave it's four walls?

Comment: There's the "Snap to Canvas Edge" option, not quite what you're asking for but it might help.